# Develop android app with intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Does intellij IDE will automatically zipalign my .apk  when export android apk file with its export wizard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does... you actually take more time writing this question than trying for your self and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks so much.I ask this question just improve I can post a question in Stackoverflow,because I have oral quiz last day,the  interviewer
ask me is there any technology bbs do you like? I said stackover flow,he doubt it and say ,you can't!I am angerly.useless man!